# Tsconfig show typescript file not found error after change file name

Tags: typescript, react-native, tsconfig, react-tsx

i changed an archive name from 'index.ts' to 'style.ts', after that always returns this error in tsconfig.json:

> "File '/src/components/AboutContainer/index.ts' not found. The file is in the program because: Matched by default include pattern '**/*'"

here's my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Closing and re-opening VSCode really seems to be the fix here. At least for me. It's something about how VSCode handles checking for problems.

Answer (score 1):

I also closed and re-opened VSCode and it was fixed.

Comment: Repeating things which someone else already said is not worth an extra answer, just upvote the already existing answer

Answer (score 0):

As `index.ts` is a code component, you might have used it somewhere in the codebase. Later, as you have changed the filename to style.ts,

- now, `index.ts` usage or import statements are incorrect as that file doesn't exist anymore
- Also, the name `[index]` before the extension `.ts` or `.js`, indicates default pattern to match is `/`.
- The solution can be, once check the usage of `index.ts` file and accordingly consider the pattern.

for example : whenever the route is default like `/` the `index.ts` code will be considered, as you have changed it, the default should be like `/new-name`

And Sometimes, restarting the IDE/Editor can be the right thing to do.

Comment: I did not use anywhere, but i just closed and reopened VsCode and the error disappeared.